# Added Hebrew Config Locales file to Rails app but database is not loading the config files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

updated -

It's using this plugin - https://github.com/iain/translatable_columns/ (5 years old)
to store the translations in the model's table
I am trying to move on to this now - https://github.com/barsoom/traco

---

I am responsible for translating the app to hebrew 
its written in 'rails', '3.0.19' 
and in ruby 1.8.7

There is a template that I used

in my config/locales/he-IL.yml

in my statements table in my schema

```
 create_table "statements", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "name_en_us"
    t.integer  "study_phase_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "position",       :default => 1, :null => false
    t.text     "name_zh_cn"
    t.text     "name_de_de"
    t.text     "name_ja_jp"
    t.text     "name_es_es"
    t.text     "name_it_it"
    t.text     "name_ar_iq"
    t.text     "name_et_ee"
    t.text     "name_da_dk"
    t.text     "name_en_ca"
    t.text     "name_en_au"
    t.text     "name_en_gb"
    t.string   "name_nl_nl"
    t.text     "name_en_sg"
    t.text     "name_sk_sk"
    t.text     "name_cs_cz"
    t.text     "name_ru_ru"
    t.string   "name_ko_kr"
    t.string   "name_pl_pl"
    t.text     "name_fr_fr"
    t.text     "name_he_he" #just added with a migration
```

the config load paths are uncommented

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = :'en-US'
```

I have checked the column name_fr_fr in my statements table and there is data there in my production database (mysql) inside the server.

and the statements are here in my he-IL.yml file

```
statements: |
  המצב בעל פוטנציאל להיות מהנה.
  המצב מורכב.
  יש עבודה שצריך לבצע
  מישהו מנסה להרשים את א'.
  מישהו מנסה לשכנע את א' במשהו.
  סומכים על א' שיעשה משהו.
  מותר לדבר.
  מותר לדבר.
  יש ציפיה או דרישה לדיבור.
  מבקשים משהו מ-א'.
  יש חשיבות לפרטים קטנים..
  המצב מעורר ערכים הקשורים לסגנון חיים או פוליטיקה.
  מספק הזדמנות להפגין יכולת אינטלקטואלית (למשל, דיון אינטלקטואלי, בעיה מסובכת שיש לפתור.)
  המצב לא ודאי.
  אדם אחר (נוכח או שדנים בו) נמצא תחת איום.
  א' מקבל ביקורת, ישירה או עקיפה.
  מישהו מנסה לנהל את או לשלוט ב-א'.
  המצב שובבני.
  התבוננות פנימה היא אפשרית. (למשל, אוירה שמאפשרת או מעודדת מחשבה על נושאים אישיים מאד)
  דברים קורים במהירות. (דירוג נמוך משמעו שדברים קורים באיטיות.)
  מישהו (נוכח או שדנים בו) עצוב או סובל.
  fנמצא אדם אחר שמרגיע.
  א' מואשם במשהו.
  יש לקבל החלטה..
  נדרשת חשיבה רציונלית.
  המצב דורש איפוק.
  המצב מערב תחרות.
  מספק הזדמנות ל-א' לעשות דברים שיגרמו לו להתחבב על אחרים או להתקבל על-ידם.
  ישנם נוכחים אחרים שצריכים או חושקים בעידוד.
  המצב מוביל לתסכול. (למשל, נמנעת השגת מטרה.)
  המשיכה הפיזית של א' רלוונטית.
  חשוב ל-א' לעשות רושם טוב.
  המצב יגרום לאנשים מסוימים מתח ועצבנות.
  המצב כולל דבר/ים קטנים מציקים.
  המצב עשוי לעורר חמימות או חמלה.
  ניתן לערער או לחבל באדם או פעילות.
  מתאפשר ל-א' להונות מישהו.
  מישהו אחר במצב (לא א') עלול להיות נכלולי.
  המצב עלול לגרום לרגשות של עוינות.
  ישנו חוסר הסכמה בין אנשים על משהו.
  מספק הזדמנות לבטא רעיונות או נקודות מבט יוצאי דופן.
  המצב מכיל איומים פיזיים.
  המצב מכיל איומים רגשיים..
  המצב מעל סוגיות מוסריות או אתיות. (למשל, מועלית דילמה מוסרית, דיון על מוסר.)
  נדרשת החלטה או פעולה מהירות.
  המצב מאפשר טווח חופשי של ביטוי רגשות.
  ייתכן שנוכחים אחרים הנם בעלי מניעים מנוגדים או נסתרים.
  המצב מעורר או עלול לעורר לחץ או טראומה
  מספק הזדמנות להרהר, לחלום בהקיץ או לפנטז.
  המצב בעל פוטנציאל לעורר אשמה אצל א'.
  יחסים אישיים קרובים קיימים או בעלי פוטנציאל להתפתח.
  סומכים על מישהו שאינו א' שיעשה משהו.
  המצב כולל גרוי אינטלקטואלי או קוגניטיבי. (למשל ספרים, הרצאות, שיחה אינטלקטואלית.)
  נדרשת אסרטיביות לצורך השגת יעד.
  המצב הוא בעל פוטנציאל לסיפוק מיידי של תשוקות. (למשל אוכל, קניות, הזדמנויות מיניות.)
  אינטראקציה חברתית היא אפשרית.
  המצב מצחיק או בעל פוטנציאל להיות מצחיק. (אם מישהו חושב שדברים כאלה מצחיקים.)
  א' הוא במוקד תשומת הלב.
  המצב כולל גרוי חושי. (למשל מגע, טעם, ריח, מגע פיזי.)
  המצב רלוונטי לבריאותו הפיזית של א'. (למשל סיכוי למחלה, ביקור רפואי.)
  הצלחה במצב זה מצריכה מודעות עצמית.
  א' שולט במשאבים הדרושים לאחרים.
  אחרים מפגינים טווח רחב של רמזים בין-אישיים. (למשל שפת גוף, טון דיבור, רמזים חברתיים.)
  המצב כולל הגבלות התנהגותיות. (למשל, חוקים או נורמות חברתיות שניתן או לא ניתן לערער
  עליהן.) המצב כולל גירויים אסתטיים. (למשל אמנות, מוסיקה, דרמה, יופי.)
  המצב עלול לעורר חרדה.
  המצב מציב דרישות מ- א'. (במפורש או במרומז.)
  מספק הזדמנות לבטא או להפגין שאפתנות.
  המצב עלול לגרום ל-א' להרגיש חסר יכולת.
  המצב כולל גירויים שניתן לפרש באופן מיני.
  דרישות המצב משתנות במהירות.
  מתעללים או פוגעים ב-א'.
  ישנם נוכחים בני המין השני.
  ישנם נוכחים בעלי פוטנציאל רומנטי עבור א'.
  המצב עשוי לעורר מוטיבציות מתחרות.
  המצב באופן בסיסי פשוט וברור.
  מספק הזדמנות לבטא קסם אישי.
  המצב כולל השוואה חברתית.
  המצב מעלה עניינים של כוח. (עבור א' או עבור נוכחים אחרים.)
  מספק הזדמנות לבטא גבריות.
  אחרים עשויים להזדקק או מבקשים לעצה מ-א'.
  העצמאות והאוטונומיה של א' מוטלות בספק או מאוימות. 
  המצב עשוי לעורר רגשית.
  מספק הזדמנות להפגין שטף מילולי. (למשל ויכוח, מונולוג, או שיחה פעילה.)
  האנשים הנוכחים הנם בעלי תפקידים חברתיים או מעמדות חברתיים שונים.
  מופעל על א' לחץ להתאים את עצמו לפעולותיהם של אחרים.
  הצלחה מצריכה שיתוף פעולה.
  משבחים או מחמיאים לא'.
  מספק הזדמנות לבטא נשיות.
```

for example in my name_en_ca column I have these statements from my en-CA.yml file in mysql production database inside my server.

```
 statements: |
      Interviews others (if present). (e.g., asks a series of questions)
      Volunteers a large amount of information about self.
      Seems interested in what someone had to say.
      Tries to control the situation. (Disregard whether attempts at control succeed or not.)
      Dominates the situation. (Disregard intention, e.g., if P dominates the situation by default because other(s) present does very little, this item should receive high placement.)
      Appears to be relaxed and comfortable.
```

There are a lot more. These exist as rows in my name_en_ca column. I am sure they got there to the db because it was loaded from the locales file.

I am sure I don't need to manually insert the translation to the new name_he_he column.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but here are some suggestions for tracking down the problem.

This system that is placing each "statement" in multiple languages into a table row does not seem familiar to me. I don't believe it is part of Rails i18n or any Gem I am familiar with. So I assume there is some custom code that pulls your .yml file content into that table. Or maybe the table is used to automatically populate .yml files? Look at your views and see where the views are getting translated texts from for display -- if they are looping through Statement.where(...).each {...} or something similar then the data is coming from the tables. You seem to be implying that, so I assume this is the case.

There is probably some code that pulls the .yml content into the table. The most likely way to do this would be a custom Rake task -- try looking at the files in lib/tasks, or just execute 'rake -T' at the command prompt and look through all the results.

There are many other ways this could be done. It could be done dynamically or as a deploy task, but there is something that needs to be configured to make it work. Someone could have made this into a migration (not a good way to do it, but possible), a 'seed' script (check in db/seeds), or custom code not in any of the usual places. Searching the entire project for "YAML.load" or just "YAML" (case-sensitive) might show you where to look -- the code will be loading the file with YAML in order to populate the database. You could also search for "Statement.create", "Statement.build", "Statement.new".

One thing that is may not be relevant but I will mention. Shouldn't `t.text "name_he_he" #just added with a migration` be `name_he_il`? If there's an automated system mapping .yml files to those column names, seems like the column name should match the file name.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes its coming for the tables, its getting shuffled in the new method of the controller for that route, `@statements = @study_phase.statements.shuffle`. There are may yml files I am sure it is the yml files populating the db not the db population the yml files. In the new.html.haml its using jquery and its going through the statements from the controller. There is a custom remove duplicate rake task in the lib/task but not a loading task.

Comment: If global searches don't turn up the code that puts the strings in the database, it's possible someone did it manually or neglected to include the script they used. If that is the case, you could write your own custom rake task to populate the table. However you would need to fully understand how to set the study_phase_id and position attributes.

Comment: I have also changed the migration column to `name_he_il`

Comment: yes the global search didn't come up with anything.